# What exactly is Stop in this question and how do I get the sum?

Tags: python, math, while-loop

[Problem Statement](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pLi7T.png)

Edit: I have transcribed the image as suggested although I think some terms are better shown in the picture if anything is unclear here;

This function takes in a positive integer n and returns the sum of the following series  Sn, as long as the absolute value of each term is larger than stop.

> Sn= 1 − 1/2 + 1/3 − 1/4 + ... + (−1)<sup>n+1</sup>/n + ...

You can assume that stop is a float value and 0 < stop < 1.

You need not round the output.

For example, if stop = 0.249, then  Sn is evaluated with only four terms.

> Sn = 1 − 1/2 + 1/3 − 1/4

For example, if stop = 0.199, then  Sn is evaluated with only five terms.

> Sn = 1 − 1/2 + 1/3 − 1/4 + 1/5

The built-in function abs() is useful. You should use a while loop.

Test cases:

```
print( alternating_while(0.249) )
print( alternating_while(0.199) )
```

gives:

```
0.5833333333333333  
0.7833333333333332
```

Now for this question, I want to get the sum of this series based on the conditions stipulated in the question.

My problem is I don't understand how to type the formula given in the question because I'm not familiar with how the while-loop works. Can someone instruct me on how to?

```
def alternating_while(stop):
    total = 0
    n = 1
    term = 1
    while abs(term) > stop:
        total= (-1) ** (n + 1) / n + alternating_while(n - 1)
        return total
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No reason to use recursion as it wasn't mentioned as a requirement.  Just check the term in the `while` loop for the stop condition:

Python 3.8+ (for the := operator):

```py
def alternating_while(stop):
    n = 1
    total = 0
    while abs(term := (-1)**(n+1)/n) > stop:
        total += term
        n += 1
    return total

print(alternating_while(0.249))
print(alternating_while(0.199))
```

Output:

```
0.5833333333333333
0.7833333333333332
```

Pre-Python 3.8 version:

```py
def alternating_while(stop):
    n = 1
    total = 0
    while True:
        term = (-1)**(n+1)/n
        if abs(term) <= stop:
            break
        total += term
        n += 1
    return total
```

Or:

```py
def alternating_while(stop):
    n = 1
    total = 0
    term = (-1)**(n+1)/n
    while abs(term) > stop:
        total += term
        n += 1
        term = (-1)**(n+1)/n    # redundant
    return total
```

Comment: Thank you! To be honest, it's my first time seeing the := operator cus we are only at like the third lesson so I'll look into it more. Thanks!

Comment: @RubyGloom `<name> := <value>` is an *assignment expression*.  It assigns the value but can be used in a larger expression.  I updated examples for pre-3.8.

Answer (score 0):

The key is "alternating".  You can just increment the current denominator one at a time.  If it is odd, you add.  Otherwise, you subtract.  `abs` is not really required; I'm not sure why they would mention it.

```
def alternating_while(stop):
    total = 0
    denom = 1
    while 1/denom > stop:
        if denom & 1:
            total += 1/denom
        else:
            total -= 1/denom
        denom += 1
    return total

print(alternating_while(0.249))
print(alternating_while(0.199))
```

Output:

```
0.5833333333333333
0.7833333333333332
```

Comment: Oh, that makes more sense. I think they only wanted abs to be used as a condition for the absolute value of the term but I'll check with my teacher again. Thank you so much!!!

Answer (score 0):

You need to cycle between adding and subtracting. The *itertools* module has a very helpful *cycle* class which you could utilise thus:

```
from itertools import cycle
from operator import add, sub

def get_term(d=2):
    while True:
        yield 1 / d
        d += 1

def calc(stop=0.199):
    c = cycle((sub, add))
    term = get_term()
    Sn = 1
    while (t := next(term)) > stop:
        Sn = next(c)(Sn, t)
    return Sn

print(calc())
```

**Output:**

```
0.6936474305598223
```

**Note:**

The reference in the problem statement to absolute values seems to be irrelevant as no terms will ever be negative

Answer (score 0):

I understand you need to use `while` in this particular problem, and this answer won't immediately help you as it is probably a few steps ahead of the current level of your course. The hope however is that you'll find it intriguing, and will perhaps come back to it in the future when you start being interested in performance and the topics introduced here.

```py
from math import ceil

def f(stop):
    n = ceil(1 / stop) - 1
    return sum([(2 * (k & 1) - 1) / k for k in range(1, n + 1)])
```

##### Explanation

1. First, we want to establish ahead of time `n`, so that we avoid a math evaluation at each loop to decide whether to stop or not. Instead, the main loop is now `for k in range(1, n + 1)` which will go from 1 to `n`, included.
2. We use the oddness of `k` (`k & 1`) to determine the sign of each term, i.e. `+1` for `k == 1`, `-1` for `k == 2`, etc.
3. We make the series of terms in a list comprehension (for speed).
4. (A point often missed by many Pythonistas): building the list using such a comprehension and then summing it is, counter-intuitively, slightly faster than summing directly from a generator. In other words, `sum([expr for k in generator])` is faster than `sum(expr for k in generator)`. Note: I haven't tested this with Python 3.11 and that version of Python has many speed improvements.

For fun, you can change slightly the loop above to return the elements of the terms and inspect them:

```py
def g(stop):
    n = ceil(1 / stop) - 1
    return [(2 * (k & 0x1) - 1, k) for k in range(1, n + 1)]

>>> g(.249)
[(1, 1), (-1, 2), (1, 3), (-1, 4)]
```